# Exporting from Cinema 4D to Keyshot garbles up geometry

Tags: cinema4d

In C4D, looks fine.:

[image]

In Keyshot (after importing .obj from C4D), all the geometry is 'generalized' and garbled... what gives? Notice the "s" now has not cavity, and "Tire Shop" is really bad.

[image]

Comment: What file type did you use to bring it to Keyshot? Chances are that the file export did go down too well and these weird artifacts have nothing to do with Keyshot. I can't remember if Keyshot opened .c4d files natively, but even so, you could try another file format or different export settings.

Comment: I tried .obj and .3ds, both did it.

Comment: Did you try to import them back to c4d? That would tell you which program is causing it.

Comment: Both of them imported back in just fine :/

No sweat though, I ended up just doing the subtitle in Photoshop to get it off to the client. I'd still like to track down a solution FFR though.

Answer (score -2):

adjust tessellation on import to keyshot